# how use "ElasticsearchRestTemplate" run "GET _cat/health?v" command?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i no find api in ElasticsearchRestTemplate class, but i want to it ,

because my self system show info in jsp/html page.

but ElasticsearchRestTemplate has about operate index/document api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Data Elasticsearch version 4.2:

Assuming that `operations` is the injected `ElasticsearchOperations` implementation (you should use this API and not `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`directly):

```
ClusterHealth clusterHealth = operations.cluster().health()
```

Comment: hi P.J.meisch，The answer is where you found it, how to query it in api doc, and how to learn this kind of knowledge. thank you !

Comment: You are Spring Data Elasticsearch project lead, oh my God, I feel really looking for the right person, ha, but can I say the official manual is too general, the key is that there is not a large number of API DEMO, so that we use spring data Elasticsearch do not know the clues, do not know where to start, hope to join more APIs, thank you.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch is a community driven project, there is no-one paid to do bug fixes, development and documentation. I am updating the docs when I change something, and if I find the time to add some missing parts I do it. But it's mostly a question of time as I am doing this in my spare time.